# Display all files, by a user contributed, in a repo

Tags: git, version-control

What's the simplest way to list all the files in a git repo a particular user contributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest one of these:

```sh
# commit + full message + list of changed files
git log --author="Frank Nord" --stat

# commit + full message
git log --author="Frank Nord"

# just commit + one line message
git log --author="Frank Nord" --format=short
```

For further options on `--format` and infos on patterns supported by `--author` see `git log --help`.

If you really need only the files, you'll need to do some grepping:

```sh
git log --author="Frank Nord" --stat --format=oneline | grep -Po "(?<=^ ).*(?=\|)" | grep -Po "[^ ]+(\s*[^ ]+)*" | sort | uniq
```

This gives you a list of unique paths ever touched by Frank Nord. It actually needs two stages of grep here, grep otherwise error'd with `exceeded PCRE's backtracking limit` :)

Answer (score 2):

The following does what you want, I think:

```
git log --diff-filter=A --author='Someone' --name-only --pretty=format: | sort -u
```

Note that the `--diff-filter=A` says to only report files that were added, and the `--pretty=format:` is just to suppress the normal output of the commit message from `git log`.

Note that this is just showing the addition of files in commits by a particular author - in the vast majority of cases it won't accurately reflect their contribution to a project, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you could always use grep for it:

```
git log | grep -B 2 -A 3 'Author: Timmy'
```

`-B num` means the number of lines to show before the match and `-A num` the number of lines after the match

Comment: This is a bad idea.  `git log` has options built-in to search for authors and it'll be a lot more effective than `grep`ing the output.